# Sending VCF files (Vcard) is failing over WhatsApp or SMS, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm sending a VCard (VCF file) in the Media URL field of a Send Message Widget but it doesn't work, it happens too with curl.

I'm creating a VCF file, storing it in a bucket and sending that URL with Content-Type text/vcard in the headers.  If I try with stock VCF files it doesn't work either.  What I'm expecting is to receive the contact file via WhatsApp or SMS and import it to my Address Book.

```
    "sid": "MMxxxxxxxxxx",
    "date_created": "Thu, 17 Oct 2019 19:43:44 +0000",
    "date_updated": "Thu, 17 Oct 2019 19:43:44 +0000",
    "date_sent": null,
    "account_sid": "ACxxxxxxxxx",
    "to": "whatsapp:+1xxxxxxx",
    "from": "whatsapp:+1xxxxxxx",
    "messaging_service_sid": null,
    "body": "media testing2",
    "status": "queued",
    "num_segments": "1",
    "num_media": "1",
    "direction": "outbound-api",
    "api_version": "2010-04-01",
    "price": null,
    "price_unit": null,
    "error_code": null,
    "error_message": null,
    "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxx/Messages/MMxxxxxxx.json",
    "subresource_uris": {
        "media": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxx/Messages/MMxxxxxxxxx/Media.json"
    }
}
```

This is the output after using this curl line

```
--data-urlencode "Body=Your Heart Health Coach contact card" \
--data-urlencode "MediaUrl=https://mighty-health-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/vcf/James%20Li.vcf" \
--data-urlencode "From=<from>" \
--data-urlencode "To=<to>" \
-u <auth>:<auth>
```

which is posted somewhere in SO [twilio]

If I send the OWL image it works as expected, but if I send the VCF URL it doesn't work.

first media testing2 message with OWL image, the second one with [w3 vcf http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/vcard-examples/john-doe.vcf](http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/vcard-examples/john-doe.vcf) and the third one with my constructed VCF file.

The headers are fine in both cases

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 22:23:17 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 18 Feb 2007 18:25:17 GMT
ETag: "3xxxxxx"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 940
Cache-Control: max-age=21600
Expires: Fri, 18 Oct 2019 04:23:17 GMT
Vary: upgrade-insecure-requests
Content-Type: text/vcard
```

and mine

```
< x-amz-id-2: xxxxxxx
< x-amz-request-id: xxxxxx
< Date: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 19:15:28 GMT
< Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 19:15:05 GMT
< ETag: "axxxxxxxx7"
< x-amz-version-id: xxxxxxxx
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: text/vcard
< Content-Length: 165
< Server: AmazonS3
```

The file is public (and removed after a while)

The studio flow logs show this:

```
From: whatsapp:+1xxxxx
Body: Conxxxxxx ⭐⭐⭐
Media URL: http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/vcard-examples/john-doe.vcf
SID: MMxxxxxxxxx
Status: queued
```

And the MEDIA box with the URL link to Twilio's CDN is present at the logs.

Any ideas??

Thanks